# excelで行の増える方向に、罫線から値まで 値から値まで 値から罫線まで 埋めたい

Tags: vba

excelで空文字を埋めたい
行の増える方向に、
罫線から値まで 埋めたい:その値
値から値まで   埋めたい:着色
値から罫線まで 埋めたい:その値

探しています。よろしくお願いします。

20200319---------------------------
チャレンジしてみました。
汎用性をもたせる方法を教えて下さい。
①maxr=50固定をはずしたい。
②1列しか出来ない。全部の列で実行したい。

```
Sub 罫線から罫線まで文字埋め()
    ic = 1
    maxr = 50
    moji = ""
    For i = 1 To maxr
        If Cells(i, ic) <> "" Then
             moji = Cells(i, ic)
         Else
             Cells(i, ic) = moji
         End If
         If Cells(i,ic).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = -4142 Then
         Else
           moji = ""
         End If
    Next
    For i = maxr To 2 Step -1                    
        If Cells(i, ic) <> "" Then
            moji = Cells(i, ic)
         Else
            Cells(i, ic) = moji
          End If
          If Cells(i - 1,ic).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = -4142 Then
          Else
             moji = ""
          End If
      Next
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

取り急ぎ、`maxr=50固定をはずしたい`　について考えてみました。

罫線の最下行番号を取得できないため、`maxr`を50に固定しているという理解で
あっておりますでしょうか？

少し時間かかってしまいますが、
`getmaxrowkeisen`という関数にて罫線のある最下行を取得し、そちらを`maxr`とするという
方法ではご要望とは異なりますでしょうか。

```
Sub 罫線から罫線まで文字埋め()

    Dim maxRowKeisen As Double
    Dim chkFlg As Boolean

    ic = 1
    maxr = getmaxrowkeisen(Rows.Count)
    moji = ""
    For i = 1 To maxr
        If Cells(i, ic) <> "" Then
             moji = Cells(i, ic)
         Else
             Cells(i, ic) = moji
         End If
         If Cells(i, ic).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = -4142 Then
         Else
           moji = ""
         End If
    Next
    For i = maxr To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, ic) <> "" Then
            moji = Cells(i, ic)
         Else
            Cells(i, ic) = moji
          End If
          If Cells(i - 1, ic).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = -4142 Then
          Else
             moji = ""
          End If
      Next
End Sub

Function getmaxrowkeisen(maxRow As Double) As Double

  Do While chkFlg = False
    If Cells(maxRow, 1).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = -4142 Then
      maxRow = maxRow - 1
    Else
      chkFlg = True
      getmaxrowkeisen = maxRow
    End If
  Loop

End Function
```